# How can I modify/view existing Form Submit rules/actions?

Tags: 2013, infopath, infopath-rules, submit

I am trying to just view (look at) existing **Form Submit Rules**. I know I can click on the **Rule Inspector** but this doesn't tell me what the rule/action is doing.

When I click on Form Submit, I can see "**Run these actions:**" but when I click on "one of these actions" I get a prompt to create a new one.

> Path when form is open in InfoPath 2013: **Data > Rules > Form
>   Submit**

How can I view existing rule actions?

Thanks,

**EDIT**
Here are some images from `InfoPath 2013` to kind of help show what I am asking.

1. Here is the **Form Submit** Rules window.

[image: Form Submit Rules]

2. When I click on an action

[image: Action link for Submit Rules]

3. This is what I see

[image]

Ass you can see, in the Rule Details, there is not option to modify or just view what the rule is actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have mentioned in your question is the right answer to view existing rule actions on `form submit` .

by Going to Data Tab > From the above ribbon , Just click on the `Form Submit` > and the Rule page will open for only `Form Submit`

[image]

But the strange behavior is when you said I **get a prompt to create a new one** ! where you should get **Rule Details dialog** that is not considered a new rule ! it shows the action detail

**Note :** create a new rule does not show a prompt dialog , it's created in place by clicking on New button.

Also, in `Rule Details dialog` you can change the action of this rule as the following and may be this the main reason that makes you fell it's a new `Rule` :

[image]

**[Update]**

Based on your question update , I would like to first elaborate what the submit action do , A `submit data action rule` submits all of the data in a form based on your selected  `Data Connection` that in your case , it's a SharePoint Library Submit 2.

And to know what the Submit action actually do as you mentioned in your comments, you will need to check the Data Connection detail that you have selected in your action by doing the following :

- Go to Data tab > Click on Data Connection  > now you should see all data connections >
- Select the data connection that you have selected before in your action  to see what action actually do in **details section** as shown below,
  In my case, it's called `Submit Email`.

[image]

Also, you can review and see the action detail as step by step or modify it by clicking modify for the selected Data Connection.

Comment: M.Qassas, When I click on a an action (your 1st img, 2nd orange box) It brings up the **Rule Details**. What i can't see, is what the action is actually _doing_. Whether it is sending the entire form in an email or etc...

Comment: Dear @IE5Master, based on your question above , you said it shows promote dialog for the new rule, so I tried to do it step by step to show to you what should show. it should show rule details rather than new rule , and now you confirm this and that's great

Comment: Regarding what the action is actually doing ? , when you click on a specific action within  run theses action , it will show the rule details dialog with what action actually doing on submit based on your selected action when you prepared it at first time ,

Comment: also , the available actions are that mentioned at my second image at drop down list that not include send mail or something like this , and the detail shows like this,  I hope you got it , please don't hesitate to tell me if you need more clarification :)

Comment: M.Qassas, First, thank you for assisting. Second, I have updated my post to include images of what I am seeing. Hopefully this can help us.

Comment: Dear @IE5Master , I really understand you , please check my answer that hopes now answer your question :)

Comment: M.Qassas, you are my new favorite person. Thank you so much for this information. You have really helped me today. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome at any time my bro